# Want to Install picasa gallery and best is PWI

Tags: javascript

I want to use http://code.google.com/p/pwi/   in drupal. it is a jquery library and with my knowledege as far as adding libraries need to code a little. need to use (hook library or add library) don't know which suits, I am not a PHP guy. but Drupal has been fun and want this badly. If little help or pointing will climb up. Tried other picasa modules like picasa node ,Brilliant gallery but none has features like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I copied the folder(js,css,images to the root ) and created a node using the demo code given. It works. Now need to find how to format it, this got me the answer but don't know whether this  is right way or not.As I am new to drupal.